# how to synchronise data in c #

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-sync-framework

I have created a WPF Application. It uses sql server compact edition database with .sdf file. In this application I have give the functionality to sync the data.I am using VS 2010. However it is syncing the record 4-5 times fine, but after that it throws exception. The error is occurring on following sample code.

```
 SampleSyncAgent syncAgent = new SampleSyncAgent();
                SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();
```

The Exception is **EXCEPTION HAS BEEN THROWN BY THE TARGET OF AN INVOCATION**.

Comment: For such exceptions check the `InnerException` property of the exception.